# TypeError _getfullpathname: path should be string, bytes or os.PathLike, not list - Problema con Staticfiles

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

Error al subir imagen en el admin. He configurado staticfiles, y parece que algo no he debido configurar bien. Antes subía sin error, pero al haber creado un directorio nuevo para imagenes y configurado staticfiles, ahora devuelve el siguiente error al subir una imagen:

**Error:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Archivo** urls.py (principal)

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, re_path, include
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('blog.urls')),
    path('dispositivo/', include('dispositivo.urls')),
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

**Archivo** settings/local.py

...

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
    '/var/www/static/',]

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "media"),
    '/var/www/media/',]
```

**Archivo** dispositivo/models.py

```
class ImagenDispositivo(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('Nombre',max_length=50)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='static/dispositivos/')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Imagen dispositivo'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Imagen de dispositivos'
        ordering = ['name']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Answer (score 0):

Parece que el problema está en las comas finales:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
    '/var/www/static/',]

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "media"),
    '/var/www/media/',]
```

Así no devuelve error:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "media")
```

(Aunque no estoy del todo seguro de que funcione igual)